# Ethernet connection on PI4

Tags: ethernet

Ethernet connection on PI4.Why are they so loose when you put the cable in the PI?
When I put it in a PC I get a click and it is a solid connection.
Putting it in the PI I push it in, but get no click to lock it. Can you buy ones that are a bit fatter so I can get a better connection? I have to keep on pushing it in.
I wonder if this is the cause of the flow message I get with Berryboot it also says can't download the OS off the internet? Sometimes it says I am not connected.

Comment: I have 3 x pi 4's - all ethernet ports "feel" identical to every other ethernet port in the place (3 x desktop PC's, 7 other pi's 1x3b+/2x3b/1x2b/3x1b, 24 port patch panel, 16 port switch, etc etc - they all feel the same) - perhaps you have some foreign substance in your pi's ethernet port

Comment: Try a replacement cable. (Or redo the RJ45 termination on your cable.)

Comment: The problem was the plastic clip on the cabal had broken off. I am not sure what the flow problem is perhaps it is a general thing that comes up it just mentions the pi3. All fine now Pinn os is working. Not Berryboot though it says firmware not found?